# Multiple backgrounds for Bootstrap sections

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, responsive-design, sections

I have one "kinky" problem with my site coding (Concrete5 Bootstrap Theme) where I need to
somehow create 2 or 4 backgrounds for all sections so that they create "corners" for all the section sides (top: left and right and bottom: left and right).

Site here: testi4.aada.fi

Any help would be great!!

I would send image but I do not have reputation for that :-)))

// Mika

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple backgrounds your css should like this.

**CSS**

```
div {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: url(background-1.png) left top no-repeat, url(background-2.png) right bottom no-repeat, url(background-3.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
```

**Or**

are you add background for corners, better you can use border-image

```
border-image: url("corner.png") 10 20 15 10 repeat stretch;
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer.. look my site now..(testi4.aada.fi) i manage to add cornes to my first section by just adding extra div with 3 columns like this: [code] <div id="esittely_ylaosa">   

    <div id="esittely_ylaosa_vasennurkka"></div>
    <div id="esittely_ylaosa_keski"></div>
    <div id="esittely_ylaosa_oikeanurkka"></div>

</div> [/code]    Now i try to do this for my "lower" cornes too but i don't know how to fill that middle div with bg-color ??

Comment: @Mika its works, did you want same as esittely_ylaosa in lower copy and paste the (esittely_ylaosa) add one more class rotate90 and add property for .rotate90{-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);} in your css

Comment: thx for answer! my problem now is that i'm not able to fill middle column with that yellow color...look demo site testi4.aada.fi..

Comment: Hi, everything is now on place .. Now i have main DIV (100%) and inside that i have 3 columns (one for each corners and one for middle)..conners width is 32px but now i want to fill middle DIV with color and make it strech between two corner DIVs..i have borders on on site so you can check them out.. --> testi4.aada.fi

Comment: The problem is you using multiple background properties. if you using both color and image your code must be written as 'background: #171616 url('/packages/bootstrap/themes/bootstrap/images/keski_bg.png') no-repeat;; like this, Next time please mention your class name.